# How to process elements added or removed from DOM by Dart Web UI template

Tags: dart, dart-webui

In (latest) Dart Web UI, what's the best way to process an element when it's added or removed from the DOM by a template? Ideally I'd like to register a callback right in the template, but that's not a requirement.

Background: I need to register/unregister certain DOM elements from two JS libraries (one of which is a JQuery plugin). Since my template uses loops and conditionals (and data binding), elements can come and go at any time, and I can't just register them after the initial rendering.

Comment: Peter, did you get this working with Web UI lifecycle methods?

Comment: Sorry, I put the project on hold and therefore haven't made progress. Nevertheless, your answer was valuable, and after more research I believe that it is the right way to solve this problem (although it still feels odd to me). Hence I'll gladly accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to add callbacks to your component's class that trigger when it is either created, inserted into the DOM, or removed from the DOM.

[Web UI Specification: Lifecycle Methods](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/spec.html#lifecycle-methods)

```
class MyComponent extends WebComponent {

  inserted() {
    // Do stuff when inserted into DOM.
  }

  removed() {
    // Do stuff when removed from DOM.
  }
}
```

Comment: The JS plugins require a certain element type to be used (e.g. a `div` or a `ul`). Would this mean that I need to extend something like `DivComponent`? Will this still be recognized as a `div` by JS/CSS? A custom web component doesn't feel quite right for this (supposedly common) requirement, but if it works, it's definitely better than nothing.

Comment: A custom component has to be declared as a type of div, paragraph or other HTML element, and then use the class you define as it's constructor, so I think you'll be fine. Have a look at how to declare a custom component ... http://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/#component-declaration, the example uses <element name="x-click-counter" constructor="CounterComponent" extends="div">. It's the cleanest way I can think of tracking insert and removal, but if your elements aren't easily componentized hopefully there's another solution.